# How to store ranges of numbers separted by comma and hyphen in an array?

Tags: arrays, string, vb.net

I have to store numbers contained in a string into arrays in a special way.
The string contains comma and hyphen.

- The comma-separated numbers should be stored individually
- Numbers separated by a hyphen should be stored as a range of values.

For example, my string is:

```
Reg. No 556002,556010-556013,556039 Cancelled
```

The array should store the numbers as:

```
(0) 556002   - Single
(1) 556010   ---------|
(2) 556011    Range of
(3) 556012    values
(4) 556013   ---------|
(5) 556039   - Single
```

I tried the following code:

```
Dim i, str
Dim array() As Char = str.ToCharArray()
Dim rnoarray() As Integer = New Integer() {}
Dim rno = ""
Dim nosta As Boolean
Dim j = 0
str = "Reg. No 556002,556010-556013,556039 Cancelled"
nosta = False
ReDim rnoarray(Len(str) + 2)
For i = 0 To Len(str)-1
If IsNumeric(array(i)) Then
rno = rno & array(i)
nosta = True
Else
If nosta = True Then
rnoarray(j) = Val(rno)
j = j + 1
nosta = False
rno = ""
End If
End If
Next
For x = 0 To j - 1
MessageBox.Show(rnoarray(x))
Next
```

But the result only includes four numbers:

```
556002
556010
556013
556039
```

Comment: As with EVERY programming problem, start by forgetting that it is a programming problem. Determine the logic that your code needs to implement before even considering writing code. Do that by determining what steps you would perform if it was a manual problem. Obviously, in this case, you would first extract that part that contains the comma delimited list of numbers, then you would split that on the delimiter, then you would convert each value to an actual number rather than text. That's what your code has to do too, so start attempting to write code to do it. Post back if you hit a snag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some steps to consider:

- Extract the *numbers* from the input string, preserving the hyphen when present
- Verify whether one of the parts contains a hyphen:

  - In this case, `Split()` the string into two parts
  - Convert to `Integer` the two parts
  - Take the minimum and the maximum values
  - Create a range of numbers between the minimum and maximum values
  - Add the range of numbers to a `List(Of Integer)`
- Convert strings that do not contain a hyphen to `Integer`
- Add the converted numbers to a `List(Of Integer)`

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim input = "Reg. No 556002,556010-556013,556039 Cancelled"
Dim numbers As New List(Of Integer)

Dim matches = Regex.Matches(input, "\d+-*\d*").OfType(Of Match)
For Each m As Match In matches
    If m.Value.Contains("-") Then
        Dim parts = m.Value.Split("-"c).Select(Function(s) Integer.Parse(s)).ToArray()
        Dim nStart As Integer = Math.Min(parts(0), parts(1))
        Dim nEnd As Integer = Math.Max(parts(0), parts(1))
        numbers.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(nStart, nEnd - nStart + 1))
    Else
        numbers.Add(Integer.Parse(m.Value))
    End If
Next
```

Without Regular Expression (assuming the input string format presented here matches the original):

```
For Each part As String In input.Split(","c)
    If part.Contains("-") Then
        Dim nValues = part.Split("-"c).Select(Function(s) Integer.Parse(s)).ToArray()
        Dim nStart As Integer = Math.Min(nValues(0), nValues(1))
        Dim nEnd As Integer = Math.Max(nValues(0), nValues(1))
        numbers.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(nStart, nEnd - nStart + 1))
    Else
        Dim sValue = String.Concat(part.Where(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c)))
        numbers.Add(Integer.Parse(sValue))
    End If
Next
```